# Set of geodesically connected points is open

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with connection, and fix a point $p$. We know that geodesics exist locally in the following sense; given any $X \in T_p M$, there is an open interval $I$ containing zero, and a geodesic $\gamma_X: I \to M$ such that $\gamma_X(0) = p$ and $\dot{\gamma}_X(0) = X$.

How do we show that there is an open set $U$ arond $p$ such that for all $y \in U$, there is a geodesic between $p$ and $y$?

It seems this is implicit in the construction of the exponential map, thus normal coordinates. I've tried thinking in terms of basic topological considerations and intuition, but can't turn this into a rigorous proof. Is this result a consequence of the existence result above?

Comment: Look in any book the definition of the exponential map associated to a connection, it one of its property.

Comment: In the books I've chosen, it seems to be taken implicitly (which hopefully means straightforward) - could you give me an overview of the method of proof (or a book with it in)?

Comment: The classic way to show this is to show that the differential of the exponential at 0  is the identity so it is locally an inverse, see Do carmo riemannian geometry for example.